# Comparison odd behaviour

Tags: c++, undefined

The following code never executes the `if` part... at the first call `level` is `0`  and `view.size() - 1` is `-1`,  but the `else` option is chosen instead ..

```
vector<int> rightSideView(TreeNode* root) {
        vector<int> solution;
        createView(root, solution, 0);
        return solution;

    }
    void createView(TreeNode* root, vector<int>& view, int level) {
        if(root == NULL)
            return;
        if(level > view.size() - 1) {
           view.push_back(root->val);
        }
        else {
            // only this part is executed
            view[level] = root->val;
        }
        createView(root->left, view, level + 1);
        createView(root->right, view, level + 1);

    }
```

The root is not `NULL` .. actually if I put a message in the `else` bracket and I have n nodes it will print n times. What's the reason for this odd behaviour?

Comment: You should got warning about signed versus unsigned comparison... *"view.size() - 1 is -1"*, no, it would be a very large number.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm using an online platform, therefore I knew nothing about such warnings

Comment: Use `static_cast<int>(view.size()) - 1`.

Comment: Or use `level + 1 > view.size()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`view.size() - 1` would be the largest number for `std::size_t` when `view.size()` is `0`, as it is `unsigned`.

Use

```
if (level > static_cast<int>(view.size()) - 1) {
```

or

```
if (level + 1 > view.size()) {
```

Comment: You display the result to `signed int`.

Comment: @gigiman "%d" tells `printf` to format a signed integer. You passed it an unsigned integer which `printf` will misinterpret because it doesn't know any better. One of the downsides of `printf` is it relies on the programmer to not lie to it (accidentally or otherwise) about the types of the inputs. Prefer `std::cout` which will print correctly or refuse to compile.